# firebase javascript compare timesamp by seconds

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, firebase-admin

I have a firebase database with some dates written down in what I think is the seconds format.
I need to check if a day has passed since that date.

```
admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()._seconds;
```

is what I am using to get the current date.
I now need to compare it, but I cannot find how to add a day to the date in the firebase, and am not sure if simply using `<` will compare them properly.

1633399860000 <-- (database date sample)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...
First of all the date format was milliseconds.
It seems like it is not a problem to compare dates with a < or >.
To add a day I tried to remove 86400000 (milliseconds) to today's date.

The code is not giving problems for now so I'm guessing it is the right solution.